# Python Restaurant Price + Tip

Tags: python

***I do not understand this at all***

```
bill = float(input("How much did the meal cost? "))
people = input("How many people are available to pay? ")

if bill < 50:
    bill2 = 1 * bill+10
else:
    bill2 = 1 * bill+20 

print("Between everyone the meal costs", bill2 / people)



ERROR: 

    print("Between everyone the meal costs", bill2 / people)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: you need to convert people to an int as well

Comment: You used `float` to convert one input string to a number, but nothing to convert the other input string to a number.

Comment: The error actually gives you the answer, if you read it... It says that you have tried to divide a float by a string (float / str) and that such operation is not supported. So, your divisor is a string and it should be a number. Fix that and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
print("Between everyone the meal costs", bill2 / int(people))
```

other solution is cast people input:

```
people = int(input("How many people are available to pay? "))
```